# jmeter different number of threads for different http request in the same thread

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-3.2, jmeter-4.0

i'm trying to implement a test plan using JMeter.

*I want to do the following scenario:*
in the same thread i have 2 HTTP Request

```
HTTP Request login
HTTP Request getStudentsName
```

the thing is **HTTP Request getStudentsName** can't be done unless i run the login first , so lets say i want to do the **login** for 1 user and then **getStudentsName** for 50 users.

if i put the **login** and **getStudentsName** in 2 different threads **login** give a success but the **getStudentsName** failed.

My question is can i implement this example in the same thread?or any other help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run  login only once use [Once Only Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) as its parent by right click, Insert Parent on the UI.

> The Once Only Logic Controller tells JMeter to process the controller(s) inside it only once per Thread, and pass over any requests under it during further iterations through the test plan.

Comment: thank you @useuser7294900 it works for me ,but i have one question , the only once controller work with loop count not number of threads(user) as i have seen in examples, so is the performance of (100 loop count + 1 user) is the same as (100 users + 1 loop count)?

Comment: It depends, but users should be faster because it can execute in parallel. For more details ask a new question

Answer (score 0):

You can use in the same thread group, Config Elements like [HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager) or [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) depending on what exactly the login implies.